# На сервере не виден заголовок Authorization, отправленный в AJAX запросе

Tags: ajax, http, https, header

Запрос:

```
var username = "ant1";
var password = "2015";

var url = 'https://test.ru/ajax.php';
$.ajax({
    type: "PROPFIND",
    url: url,
    success: function(json) {
        alert("Success", json);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("withCredentials", "true");
        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
    }
});
```

Проблема: на сервере, при просмотре $_SERVER переменная [HTTP_AUTHORIZATION] = "", хотя там должно быть Basic *****. В чем беда? Куда смотреть?

Comment: А она там точно должна быть? http://php.net/manual/ru/features.http-auth.php

Comment: @Visman,  Вот именно, что там ничего нет NULL. Как я понимаю, при таком заголовке данные из Authorization падают в HTTP_AUTHORIZATION и потом оттуда падают в PHP_AUTH_USER и PHP_AUTH_PW. Беда в том, что данные, которые я отправляю в заголовке не приходят на сайт...

Comment: Покажите, что у вас из браузера уходит при ajax. В инструментах разработки, вкладка сеть, заголовки запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за внимание, ответ найден. Для тех, кто сталкивается с подобной проблемой мое решение:

При отправке "непростых" запросов (а это все запросы кроме GET, POST, HEAD) методом ajax/cors Браузер отправляет **2 запроса**: 1 preflight, 2 основной.

В моем случае сервер почему-то (???) принимал первый запрос preflight и отбрасывал второй.

Ситуация разрешилась простым условием на наличие определенного заголовка.

Спасибо @sanmai, за то, что подтолкнул меня к мысли подробного разбора запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно смотреть эти две переменные.

```
var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
```

Логин и пароль попадают в них.

Заголовок, который вы хотите увидеть, в штатной конфигурации не заполняется и не пока­зы­вает­ся. Если вы хотите его увидеть, то этого нужно добиваться. Под Apache 2 это делается та­ким правилом:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Если же после всего у вас всё равно не видны логин и пароль, попробуйте проверить что про­блема действительно в AJAX, а не в настройках сервера. Если ваш прямой запрос с ло­ги­ном и паролем тоже не проходит на сервер, то значит дело точно не в AJAX.

```
curl --user username:password https://test.ru/ajax.php
```

Если же логин и пароль при прямом запросе видны, а при AJAX - не видны, то можно посмо­треть в сторону CORS. Если запросы у вас идут с другого хоста, то дело в них. Проверить, какие именно заголовки не передаются из-за ограничений CORS, можно в браузерной кон­соли.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/198476)

Comment: @sanmai, Вот именно, что там ничего нет NULL. Как я понимаю, при таком заголовке данные из Authorization падают в HTTP_AUTHORIZATION и потом оттуда падают в PHP_AUTH_USER и PHP_AUTH_PW. Беда в том, что данные, которые я отправляю в заголовке не приходят на сайт...

Comment: @Anatol поделитесь соображениями: почему не ответ?

Comment: @sanmai попросту то, что было до правки *Вам нужно смотреть эти две переменные.
var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']);
Логин и пароль попадают в них.* не дотягивало до ответа, по моему скромному мнению

Comment: теперь же - вполне